# number of matches in two sequences with STL

Tags: c++, stl

OK, here is yet another question of the "How to do it better in STL?" series.

We have two ranges, designated by first1, last1, and first2. We want to find the number of different i's from [0, last1-first1] such that `*(first1 + i) == *(first2 + i)`

For example:

```
{a, b, c, d, d, b, c, a}
{a, a, b, c, d, c, c, a}
 ^           ^     ^  ^
```

For these two ranges the answer is 4.

Is there a good STL way to do it? I mean preferrably without any manual for's, while's etc. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's good way to do it without manual loops.

Comment: @Kenny: there must be. In other languages it’s as easy as `sum . zipWith (\x y if x == y then 1 else 0)`

Comment: @Konrad: C++'s `zipWith` (`transform`) need a custom output iterator.

Comment: @Kenny: `zipWith` is more like `inner_product` than `transform`. As for the output iterator, doesn’t Boost offer something in the form of output adaptors? Granted, the situation isn’t perfect … I’m really a bit sad at C++’ half-hearted support for such scenarios. The algorithms are all there, but writing the necessary functors and iterator adaptors by hand is a major pain.

Comment: @Konrad: C++'s `inner_product` is `foldl'` composed with `zipWith`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
std::inner_product(first1, last1, first2, 0, std::plus<T>(), std::equal_to<T>());
```

**UPDATE**

Konrad has pointed out in the comments below that this relies on slightly nefarious implicit conversion from `bool` to `int`.  Whilst this is completely legal, it can be avoided thus:

```
template <typename T>
int match(const T &a, const T &b) { return (a == b) ? 1 : 0; }

std::inner_product(first1, last1, first2, 0, std::plus<T>(), match<T>);
```

Comment: OMG, this is just so concise it rocks!

Comment: I have to admit that I don’t like this solution since it only works because `true` happens to be implemented as `1` underneath, and can be converted implicitly. Somehow, mixing functional programming with “low-level” abstraction leaks just rubs me the wrong way. However, it’s indisputably the *shortest* solution.

Comment: Anybody up for a solution that does the same with 3 input sequences?

Comment: @André: I don't believe there are any STL algorithms that iterate over *three* iterators.

Comment: @Konrad: It's not just an "happens to be implemented" thing. The standard *requires* `true` to be converted to 1 and `false` to 0. (C++ §[conv.integral]/4)

Comment: @Oli Chalesworth: I know, that's why I love Python's `zip()` function :-) http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip . Actually, I like C++ less and less precisely because a lot of the STL is hard to generalize to higher amounts of data. Algorithms are painful enough to write for the 1 and 2 sequence cases as is. Writing a generic n-sequence version is just about impossible.

Comment: @Kenny: I know that it’s well-defined (and I was very careful in my formulation to not say otherwise). It’s still a leaky abstraction. Functional programming (in my mind) is inherently very high level programming. While the fact that you can actually write `true == 1` in C++ is a dirty, dirty linnen inherited from oh-so-close-to-the-machine C.

Comment: @Konrad: In my mind that's about strong typing / disallowing implicit conversion, not about functional programming. Even in Python `True` and `False` are defined to be 1 and 0 (I know Python's main feature isn't about functional).

Comment: @Kenny: the point isn’t that booleans happen to be implemented as numbers deep down in the computer (after all, everything is). My aversion is to rely on this implementation in high-level code. There *shouldn’t* be an implicit conversion between integers and booleans, period. … Of course, since it exists, one can as well rely on it. Oli’s code is fine, I’ve just remembered that I had already written the exact same code myself (to calculate Hamming distances …). But I don’t like that you *can* write this code in the first place. It’s dirty.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with the following solution, insipired by functional languages' `zip()`functions. It compiles and runs fine, but IMHO, this is probably the most unsafe use of `begin()` & `end()` iterator pairs I've ever come across, so I don't recommend using it in production code as is.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace {

        // Iterator for pairs of items at same position in two sequences.
    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    class zipper
    {
            // Keep track of position in input sequences.
        Lhs myLhs;
        Rhs myRhs;
    public:
            // Minimal assumptions on iterator types `Lhs` and `Rhs`.
        typedef std::input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef std::pair<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Lhs>::value_type,
            typename std::iterator_traits<Rhs>::value_type
        > value_type;
        typedef value_type& reference;
        typedef value_type* pointer;
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

        zipper ( Lhs lhs, Rhs rhs )
            : myLhs(lhs), myRhs(rhs)
        {}
        value_type operator* () const {
            return (value_type(*myLhs, *myRhs));
        }
        bool operator== ( const zipper<Lhs,Rhs>& other ) const {
            return ((myLhs == other.myLhs) && (myRhs == other.myRhs));
        }
        bool operator!= ( const zipper<Lhs,Rhs>& other ) const {
            return ((myLhs != other.myLhs) || (myRhs != other.myRhs));
        }
        zipper<Lhs,Rhs>& operator++ () {
            ++myLhs, ++myRhs; return (*this);
        }
        zipper<Lhs,Rhs> operator++ ( int ) {
            const zipper<Lhs,Rhs> old(*this);
            ++(*this); return (old);
        }
    };

       // Shorthand "a la" std::make_pair().
    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    zipper<Lhs,Rhs> make_zipper ( Lhs lhs, Rhs rhs )
    {
        return (zipper<Lhs,Rhs>(lhs, rhs));
    }

        // Check for equal items in a pair.
    template<typename T> struct equal_pair
    {
        bool operator() ( const std::pair<T,T>& x ) const
        {
            return (x.first == x.second);
        }
    };

}

int main ( int, char ** )
{
        // Test data.
    const std::string lhs("abcddbca");
    const std::string rhs("aabcdcca");

        // Count how many pairs are equal.
    const std::size_t equal_pairs = std::count_if(
        make_zipper(lhs.begin(),rhs.begin()),
        make_zipper(lhs.end()  ,rhs.end()  ), equal_pair<char>());

        // Outputs "There are 4 equal pairs.".
    std::cout
        << "There are " << equal_pairs << " equal pairs." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted one. Definitely +1!

Comment: @missingfaktor: actually, I like Oli Charlesworth's solution better than this one, as far as solving the problem in the question. However, this `zipper` class happens to solve more general problems! I just wish I could come up with a proper n-sequence version of this using variable template arguments and generic tuples in some readable fashion.

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse the std::mismatch algorithm (and lambda function):

```
const int lista[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1 };
const int listb[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1 };
int count = 0;

std::mismatch(lista, lista+8, listb, [&count](int a, int b)->bool
{
    if (a == b) ++count;
    return true;
});

std::cout << count << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [std::transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/391xya49.aspx) on the two ranges with a stateful binary functor that increments a counter on match.

Holding my nose, since this keeps state as a static member.  You can avoid the 'write back to source' that @Johannes raised using `equal` rather than `transform` but statefulness via `static` is still messy here (in my code anyhow).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class match {
public:
    char operator()(const char& lhs, const char& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs == rhs)
        {
            ++count;
        }
        return rhs;
    }
    static size_t count;
};

size_t match::count(0);

class matchEqual {
public:
    bool operator()(const char& lhs, const char& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs == rhs)
        {
            ++count;
        }
        return false;
    }
    static size_t count;
};

size_t matchEqual::count(0);

int main()
{

    vector<char> vec1;
    vec1.push_back('a');
    vec1.push_back('b');
    vec1.push_back('c');
    vec1.push_back('d');
    vec1.push_back('d');
    vec1.push_back('b');
    vec1.push_back('c');
    vec1.push_back('a');

    vector<char> vec2;
    vec2.push_back('a');
    vec2.push_back('a');
    vec2.push_back('b');
    vec2.push_back('c');
    vec2.push_back('d');
    vec2.push_back('c');
    vec2.push_back('c');
    vec2.push_back('a');

    transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.begin(), match());

    size_t matches = match::count;

    equal(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), matchEqual());
    matches = matchEqual::count;

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: we aren't technically allowed stateful functors are we?

Comment: I don't think the functor for `std::transform` is allowed to be stateful (see http://www.drdobbs.com/184403769).  In practice, you'll probably get away with it.

Comment: The more serious problem is - what do you do with the output iterator? Writing the value back into one of the sequences would be quite poor. Writing a noop output iterator for only this purpose would just be freaking weird. Also, writing a stateful binary functor could violate his requirement "without any manual for's, while's etc." (though some people like to write more than necessary, just for the sake of using STL algorithms, and hate loops but love big class definitions).

Comment: @Johannes, yes that is not great. That's precisely what my code does - `vec2` is both source2 and dest.  Any other approaches?