# C++ Sort vector of <T> according to vector of double

Tags: c++

I want to sort a vector of T according to a vector of double. That is, if I have

```
vector<T> a;
vector<double>b;
```

If `a` is `{t1, t2, t3, t4}` and `b` is `{3, 1, 5, 2}`, I want to obtain `{t2, t4, t1, t3}`.

I don't know how to declare the template. I'm trying something like

```
template<vector<class T>> vector<T> sortByArray(vector<T> a, vector<double>b)
```

And I don't have any idea of how to write the function body either.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is the usage of my algorithm. I don't get it right.

```
template <typename T> struct dataPair
{
    dataPair(double s, T o) 
    : m_sortData(s)
    , m_otherData(o)
    {

    }

    bool operator< (const dataPair &rhs) { return (m_sortData < rhs.m_sortData); }

    double m_sortData;
    T m_otherData;

}



  template <class T> vector<T> sortByArrayStuff(vector<T> objects, vector<double> sortNumber) {
    vector<dataPair<T>> v;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        v.push_back(dataPair<T>(objects[i], sortNumber[i]));
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    vector<T> retVal;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        retVal.push_back(dataPair<T>(objects[i], sortNumber[i]));
    }
    return retVal;
};
```

I want to use the same template for vectors of "Points" and vectors of vectors of "Points":

```
vector<double> sortedAreas;
vector<Point> sortedPoints = sortByArray<vector<Point>>(points, sortedAreas);
vector<vector<Point>> sortedContours = sortByArray<vector<vector<Point>>>(contours, sortedAreas);
```

Error is

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'dataPair<T>' to 'cv::Point &&'
          with
          [
              _Ty=cv::Point
          ]
          and
          [
              T=cv::Point
          ]
          Reason: cannot convert from 'dataPair<T>' to 'cv::Point'
          with
          [
              T=cv::Point
          ]
```

Comment: What is the relationship between your `a` and `b` and your result? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Don't write a new function. Write a comparator that you provide to `std::sort`. (But you meant `template <typename T>`, and probably should have accepted those function arguments as `refs-to-const`).

Comment: http://www.stanford.edu/~dgleich/notebook/2006/03/sorting_two_arrays_simultaneou.html

Comment: What do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: Your error is probably due to declaring retVal as `vector<T>` but trying to push `dataPair<T>` into it. I think you need `retVal.push_back(v[i].m_otherData)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is create a `struct` or `class` like this:

```
template <typename T> struct dataPair
{
    dataPair(double s, T o) 
    : m_sortData(s)
    , m_otherData(o)
    {

    }

    bool operator< (const dataPair &rhs) { return (m_sortData < rhs.m_sortData); }

    double m_sortData;
    T m_otherData;

}
```

Then, you create a vector of these `dataPair` types

```
{
    // your code ...
    // that assumes b is is a std::vector<YourType>

    // create vector and populate it
    std::vector<dataPair<YourType>> v;
    v.push_back(dataPair<YourType>(a[0],b[0]));
    v.push_back(dataPair<YourType>(a[1],b[1]));
    v.push_back(dataPair<YourType>(a[2],b[2]));
    v.push_back(dataPair<YourType>(a[3],b[3]));

    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());

    // your code (now they will be sorted how you like in v)
```

}

EDIT: had some typos

EDIT2:  You can also do this with functors for more efficiency, but this is the basic idea.

EDIT3:  [Using functors with sort is described very nicely here.  See where they use the functor `myclass` in which they overload operator().  This allows compile-time optimizations to be made (because from `std::sort`'s perspective the sorting criterion is a template type)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: Why not go for a `std::pair<double, something>` and write a functor? much easier to digest and as you say, more efficient.

Comment: Yes, good point. It's the same concept and `pair` is already done by the STL so that's good too.

Comment: Could you show what the functor version looks like? Do I need to inherit from std::pair and define operator<? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of, is if you just included the double within your class declaration of T, and used it as your sorting parameter.  Sorry if my template syntax is not that great, its been a while since ive used them:

```
class YourClass
{
  //Some stuff...
  double sortVal;
};

bool std::less<YourClass>(YourClass left, YourClass  right)
{
   return left.sortVal < right.sortval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing something like this the other day, and here was my idea.  Take both vectors, and combine them into a multimap.  The sorting will be done automatically just by inserting them into the map, then you extract them from the map back into the vectors.  I came up with 2 function templates for this job, here they are:

```
// This function basically does the reverse of a transform.  Whereas transform takes
// two inputs and by some method merges them into one, this function takes one input
// and by some method splits it in two.
template<typename InIt, typename Out1It, typename Out2It, typename Fn>
void fork_transform(InIt ibegin, InIt iend, Out1It o1begin, Out2It o2begin, Fn fork)
{
    while(ibegin != iend)
    {
        fork(*ibegin, *o1begin, *o2begin);
        ++o1begin;
        ++o2begin;
        ++ibegin;
    }
}

template<typename ItPrimary, typename ItSecondary>
void simul_sort(ItPrimary begin1, ItPrimary end1, ItSecondary begin2)
{
    typedef std::iterator_traits<ItPrimary>::value_type T1;
    typedef std::iterator_traits<ItSecondary>::value_type T2;

    typedef std::multimap<T1,T2> Map_t;
    typedef Map_t::value_type Pair_t;

    Map_t m;

    // this was necessary for me because of a bug in VC10, see my most recent question
    auto MakePair = [](const T1 & first, const T2 & second) { return std::make_pair(first,second); };
    std::transform(begin1, end1, begin2, std::inserter(m,m.begin()), MakePair);

    auto Fork = [](const Pair_t & p, T1 & first, T2 & second) { first = p.first; second = p.second; };
    fork_transform(m.begin(), m.end(), begin1, begin2, Fork);
}
```

This actually sorts both vectors simultaneously.  The first is sorted normally, the second is sorted according to the order of the first:

```
simul_sort(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need generic solution for the problem then take a look on zipper template in one of answers here:
[number of matches in two sequences with STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125536/number-of-matches-in-two-sequences-with-stl)

You will need something close to that zipper - some entity that zips two sequences into one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution - a function which returns a vector of the indexes into an array. You can use these indexes on either of your `a` or `b` to get them in sorted order.

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator>
struct IndirectCompare : public std::binary_function<size_t, size_t, bool>
{
    IndirectCompare(RandomAccessIterator first) : m_first(first)
    {
    }
    bool operator()(const size_t &left, const size_t &right)
    {
        return *(m_first + left) < *(m_first + right);
    }
    RandomAccessIterator m_first;
};

template<class RandomAccessIterator>
std::vector<size_t> ordered_index(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
{
    size_t n = last - first;
    std::vector<size_t> result;
    result.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < n;  ++i)
        result.push_back(i);
    IndirectCompare<RandomAccessIterator> comp(first);
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(), comp);
    return result;
}
```

P.S. I've tested this code now, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort two vectors simultaneously, you should rather create a std::vector (say c) of std::pair. **First component must be the one which is to be sorted normally and second must be the one to be sorted accordingly.**

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, T>> c;
std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
```

Hope this helps.